# Find row limit in the excel worksheet using c#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I have 12,00,000 records and have to generate an excel file. while generating I found the excel sheet was allow only 10,00,000+ records. while adding these records I am getting the exception. to avoid that I found one solution if we found rows limit of excel sheet which allow the no. of rows. by comparing we can add the limit raged data.

Now, my main problem was how to find the row limit of the excel sheet programmatically ?. please help with this one.

Thank You.

Comment: It's the `worksheet.rows.count` property

Comment: I think it will return only the records count which is added to the sheet. I need how many records can support the sheet.

Comment: "12,00,000"? did you mean 12 million or 1.2 million?

Comment: @SolarMike it's [lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)

Comment: it is 1.2 million

Answer (score 0):

After a long effort on finding how many rows the excel sheet will support for each sheet. I found one line of code which was returns the row limit of excel sheet.

```
workSheet.Cells.Rows
```